# Property does not exists on type when using union with index signature

Tags: typescript, union-types, index-signature

Let's assume we have following interfaces:

```
interface A {
  type: 'A';
  value: {
    a: 3,
  };
}

interface B {
  type: 'B';
  value: {
    b: 3,
  };
}
```

I create another interface which uses union of these interfaces:

```
interface C {
  detail: A | B;
}
```

Now we should be able to detect type `A` or `B` using their `type` property:

```
function test(arg: C) {
  if (arg.detail.type === 'A') {
    arg.detail.value.a;
  } else if (arg.detail.type === 'B') {
    arg.detail.value.b;
  }
}
```

There is no error as we expected it.

**Problem:**
Let's make another interface which has index signature:

```
interface cArr {
  [index: string]: C;
}
```

**I expect to detect type of values of `cArr` type same as `arg` variable with their `type` property**:

```
function test(arg2: cArr, ID: string) {
  if (arg2[ID].detail.type === 'A') {
    arg2[ID].detail.value.a;
  }
}
```

But typescript gives me following error:

```
Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ a: 3; } | { b: 3; }'.
  Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ b: 3; }'.
```

What's the problem? Why `if` statement couldn't narrow down type of `arg2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's inference is limited when it comes to indexed properties, so just store the object whose type you want to infer in a new variable:

```
function test(arg2: cArr, ID: string) {
    const item = arg2[ID];
    if (item.detail.type === 'A') {
        item.detail.value.a;
    }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20WATwAcIAuZAclQoG4c8A3OAGwFczN6885yBmADRdkAXzoisWUJFiIUAIU7dCJchXm1hTNh2zduAI35DuYrBKnho8JMgDCSvABMIYOMGbl0AH2TzxkpYyNigIqFBQjrgA2qAuAB7kAM5gUKAA5gC65HYBWDCsIAhgwAD2IPgQKQAUcFDpAEzkYRECyACSACLJqRkAlFHICOUpyMCQALbIALzIdY3RXZl03MAwyNXjEBMAdC5uHjsqKNOnlNQDevq4W7v77sw72uw7cCt4EiJAA)

Comment: This limitation of typescript is really strange! Your suggestion made it, thank you.